# FsUnit.xUnit FSharp.Core assembly binding

Tags: f#, xunit, fsunit

I'm trying to write a unit test project using FSUnit.xUnit.

Throughout my development on this process, I have been plagued by tests failing with this message (not always citing the same version):

```
Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=3.259.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Adding binding redirects seems to have no effect. My latest one is:

```
  <configuration>
    <runtime>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </runtime>
    <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
    </startup>
  </configuration>
```

The only thing that has worked up until now is downgrading the FSharp.Core NuGet package, but in this latest incarnation even this has failed.

I am losing a lot of time over this issue. Any help will be very gratefully received.

**UPDATE**

From what I can make out, this is due to a bug in Json.NET. The tests are running, but the error is being thrown within the assembly while I am serialising and deserialising discriminated unions. I have submitted an issue in Json.NET.

**FURTHER UPDATE**

I am calling the Json.NET serialiser from a test project targeting F# Version 4.4.0.0, and the object I'm trying to serialise is defined in a portable assembly with Profile259 (portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8). The portable assembly contains the same binding redirects.

Comment: Do you have a separate test project? The redirect is in there as well? Just to make sure...

Comment: I do, but it's a different project profile. I'll add more details soon.